# Google MAP V2 - Map Not Showing On Real Phone

Tags: java, android

I've implemented Google Maps v2 on my emulator, it works fine and displays but I need to test this on an android phone however the map just displays with a blank white screen with zoom buttons. I'm using the debug API key, i don't want to generate a release key just yet, can I still test my maps on a real phone with a debug API key?

If not where can I find the *.keystroke file required to enable me to generate a release key?

Comment: which IDE are you working in? are you uploading from the IDE, or are you exporting the project to an apk and then uploading the apk?

Comment: debug key should work just fine, have you followed the steps in details, slight changes was made to the steps, have you included play google_play_services_version in your manifest.xml ?

Comment: Why have you decided it's an API key issue? Do you see anything on the logcat? Does your device's ROM have Google Services? What's the device and ROM?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the whole answer but I know you can get the api key on this website :

Visit the APIs Console at https://code.google.com/apis/console and log in with your Google Account.
Click the api&auth link from the left-hand menu.
Activate the Google Maps API v2 service.
Click the credential link from the left-hand menu.

You'll then find on the right panel the API key

Comment: broken link, also, does debug key work with google maps on real phone?

Comment: indeed, I edited my post, can you tell me if it helps ? I've always used the real key on my real device so I can't give an answer on that point, I'm sorry

Comment: The API key i do have, but for debug mode, however what I want to know is, can this same key work on a real phone?

Comment: @TwoStarII the debug key should work just fine, check my comment on the original question on top.

Comment: @Saksak I have declared it yes:   <meta-data 
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: Also to note, after I've compiled my app I just copied the .apk file and installed that on my phone, do I need to copy any certificates as well?

Comment: @TwoStarII why not to run the application from the IDE instead of copying the generated APK ? even though there is anything else need to be copied.

Comment: I have generated a release key and the map works fine on the real device now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that you compile the app then copy it over I believe this might be the answer.

First remove the app from the phone.
Next plug the phone into the computer via the USB cable (make sure the computer recognizes the phone)

(assuming you are using eclipse)

right click on the project, select run as android application.

From the list select your device, and it should upload the app to your phone using the debugging key with out the need of a production key for the map api

Comment: I'll try that on my next compile and provide feedback ...although I don't mind because I have both keys in my mainfest I just comment out the one i don't need (1 for emulator 1 for phone)

Answer (score 0):

If Map Working on Emulator then it should be work on real Device . There should be no problem with [console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). Just check for Google Play Service. I think in map white screen with grids are shown. If map shows on Emulator using debug key then it also shows on real Device.